# NumeralJS No decimal formatting/rounding

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

I use NumeralJS for formatting amounts as below;

```
numeral(unformattedValue).format(amtFormat);
```

So if the amtFormat is set as "0,0.00", then if the amount is entered as "123.1", I get it as "123.10"

But what I want is no formatting/rounding, etc to take place after the decimal...
Thus, if the entered value is 1.999999, I want the output to be 1.999999 (No change after the decimal at all)

Is it possible to pass something to the format() to achieve this ? I could not find anything in the NumeralJS documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why call `format` if you don't need any formatting? Could you just call `value()`?

Comment: Actually, there are 2 things...thousand separator formatting (which I want to be applied), but the decimals should stay as it is...

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements of:

- Formatting the thousands separator
- Keeping the decimals "as-is"

One option you could try is below. There might be a simpler way to do this, perhaps by defining a custom `format`, but here's one thought:

```js
// example input
let input = [1549.9988, 1549123.9912938, 123.456];

input.forEach(i => {

    // count the number of decimals
    let numberOfDecimals = i.toString().split(".")[1].length;

    // construct a string representing the number of decimals to retain
    let decFormat = "0".repeat(numberOfDecimals - 1);

    // format the number using this string
    let num = numeral(i).format("0,0[." + decFormat + "]");

    console.log(num);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..actually generating random number of 0s to format is something which I have tried already and it works perfectly...What I was looking for is if there is any way of avoiding that and using some built-in way of NumeralJS to achieve the same....

Comment: I looked a bit into how `format` works, and short of creating your own custom format where you could apply a regex, it looks like there aren't many (if any) other built-in options. I agree this would be a useful feature though. Might be worth opening up an issue on GitHub with the dev team.